# Removing ‘<b/>’ with a userscript

Tags: javascript, regex

I frequently use a website where some pages erroneously contain a singular `<b/>`, resulting in all following text being bold. I’m trying to write a userscript to get around this, but the following JS code doesn’t work:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<b\/>/g, '')
```

Why?

Comment: Use the DOM to do this.  Don't use regex.  You shouldn't ever use regex to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

A nice and *safe* way to do this would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('b').forEach(b => {
  // const parent = b.parentNode;
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.append(...b.childNodes);
  b.replaceWith(fragment);
  // (optional) to join consecutive textNodes
  // parent.normalize();
});
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('b').forEach(b => {
    const parent = b.parentNode;
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.append(...b.childNodes);
    b.replaceWith(fragment);
    parent.normalize();
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque posuere neque, ac consectetur turpis porta vel. Nullam consequat mauris quis lectus porttitor, id vehicula lorem maximus. Nunc laoreet velit nisl. Nunc sit amet nulla egestas, <b>tincidunt magna sed, hendrerit ante.</b> Vestibulum elementum porttitor nisi quis commodo. Morbi gravida odio a eros pretium, at sagittis velit iaculis. Ut quis eleifend tortor. Etiam consectetur congue tempor. Pellentesque vel gravida velit. Maecenas quis urna ante. Morbi vel tellus eros.
</p>
<p>
Nulla scelerisque vitae lacus quis consequat. Donec volutpat efficitur diam non lobortis. Donec porttitor in lorem vitae iaculis. Suspendisse eu ligula a arcu ultrices scelerisque vitae at lacus. Fusce sodales, nunc ac tincidunt dignissim, velit felis pellentesque odio, ac mattis orci eros molestie est. Aliquam euismod cursus sem, nec convallis libero aliquam vel. Aliquam ut velit ornare risus sollicitudin convallis. <b>Etiam massa sem, facilisis vel hendrerit vitae, <b>dignissim fermentum nulla.</b> Nullam pellentesque ipsum eu egestas convallis.</b> Maecenas scelerisque vitae nisl at tempor. Etiam eu egestas nibh. Phasellus vitae consectetur velit, sed fringilla metus. Nunc vitae pellentesque arcu. Nullam eget felis id ligula molestie placerat. Aliquam gravida pulvinar posuere. Nullam non purus consequat, volutpat enim eu, convallis ante.
</p>
<p>
<b>Quisque egestas</b> enim sed felis scelerisque ultrices. Proin id justo vitae ante volutpat tristique a nec metus. Vivamus quis scelerisque nunc, vitae dictum nunc. Vestibulum ultrices sem sit amet facilisis ornare. Sed tellus libero, vestibulum molestie ultricies a, cursus a nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed ante tortor. Suspendisse eu sem quis velit aliquam tempus. Vivamus eget vulputate est, nec fermentum sem. Suspendisse potenti. In nunc ante, tincidunt ut nunc id, tempor aliquam mi. Vestibulum dictum, mi sed tempus commodo, ex turpis aliquam felis, suscipit aliquet leo eros tempor nisi. Donec et suscipit risus. Proin vestibulum felis interdum tellus luctus, nec tempus turpis cursus. Curabitur lectus nibh, scelerisque ut magna sed, aliquet mollis risus. Sed pulvinar, felis at sodales porta, enim neque rhoncus nulla, eget ornare odio lectus facilisis dolor.
</p>
```

To support ES5 (not sure why you'd need to at this point), here's a more verbose alternative that also happens to be more efficient than above:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('b');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var b = nodes[i];
  var parent = b.parentNode;
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (var j = 0; j < b.childNodes.length; j++) {
    fragment.appendChild(b.childNodes[j]);
  }

  parent.replaceChild(fragment, b);

  // check for DOM level 2 support
  if (typeof parent.normalize === 'function') {
    // this step is not required
    // just re-optimizes DOM layout
    parent.normalize();
  }
}
```

#### See:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)
- [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)
- [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)
- [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [`Node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize)

Comment: This also removes all boldness.

Comment: @J.Doe that's the point...? All these answers remove all boldness. There's no way to detect an "erroneous `<b/>`"

Comment: @J.Doe there's no way for JavaScript to inspect the page's raw HTML. The only way to do that would be to fetch the page through AJAX as a text response and inject it into the DOM with the regex removal applied, which is extremely inadvisable, as most modern websites using popular frameworks like react and angular would not be able to handle such an extreme modification to the DOM. In addition, doing so would re-run any `<script>`s that were injected, almost certainly causing more errors in the page for any website.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Doesn’t `.replace()` just match a string given to it to a regex? It does catch `</b>` (slash-b, not b-slash), for instance.

Comment: @J.Doe JavaScript only has access to the DOM. The DOM is the result of the HTML _having already been parsed_. It sanitizes things like `<b/>` into occasionally undesirable results as you're seeing, but accessing `innerHTML` shows the serialization of the DOM, rather than the original HTML string that was parsed. I did just think of one (really awful, but functional) solution, so I'll try it. If it works, I'll include it here.

Comment: As it turns out, the response to invalid markup is browser-specific. Chrome, for example, [has a cascading effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMsHh.png) when parsing `<b/>`. With my previous explanation in mind about why it's bad to string replace the entire document, fixing this particular error via JavaScript is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for trying!

Answer (score 0):

The dom can't contain a single `<b/>`, it must have a `<b>` before.

The correct regex would be :

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<b\/?>/g, '')
```

Comment: This also removes any `<b>`, though.